# Heavy CPU load with "dark theme" on eclipse (linux)

Tags: linux, eclipse

As soon as I switch from the classic to the dark theme, my fan starts spinning. Looking with `top`, *xorg* and *java* either taking about 70% CPU load constantly ("4" cpu's HT) just for idling around. Calling the preferences menu then, makes things even worse.
Even plain text is better than the standard color theme.

I'm on arch64, defaulting JDK-7/8 (oracle) is all the same.
Maybe a GTK configuration issue?